# Why 'the top of the page' but 'the top of page 33'?

Tags: articles

Why we don't use the definite article 'the' before 'page 33'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definite article 'the' and the cardinal number '33' are both determiners, and nouns (in this case 'page') only take one determiner.

[TheFreeDictionary: Determiners](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Determiners.htm)

Comment: Thank you. But why we should say 'in the year 2003' but 'page 33'?

Comment: it's in the preposition - 'year 2003' becomes a noun phrase and needs a determiner

Comment: JonMark, I've got it! Thanks! And one more quesion, I thought that 33 in my case is a cardinal number, not ordinal, am I wrong?

Comment: Probably - I read TFD's definition as ordinal meaning position in a list, which a book sort of is. Then I remembered ordinals are usually 1st, 2nd. I'll edit I think.